# Setting SharedPreferences (NOT DefaultSharedPreferences) to default values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

May be I'm just a little confused but I'm having troubles to figure out how to set default values of a particular SharedPreferences.

As far as I understand, the approach

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(ctx, R.xml.myprefs, true);
```

only works for the DefaultSharedPreferences. In my case I use different SharedPreferences and I have to set the default values of one of them which is NOT the DefaultSharedPreferences. So I miss something like

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(mySharedPrefs, R.xml.myprefs, true).
```

Am I overlooking something??

Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PreferenceManager` class [overloads this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) to make it possible to specify the preference file and mode:

```
public static void setDefaultValues(Context context, String sharedPreferencesName, 
                                    int sharedPreferencesMode, int resId, boolean readAgain)
```

Excerpt from the reference:

> Similar to setDefaultValues(Context, int, boolean) but allows the
>   client to provide the filename and mode of the shared preferences
>   file.

Although you cannot pass the `SharedPreference` object itself as a parameter, passing the correct **sharedPreferencesName** and **sharedPreferencesMode** of your preferences file will point to the same exact instance.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!